# Can't use enums in CompareExchange. (The type enum must be a reference type in order to use it in CompareExchange)

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

To my surprise I can't use CompareExcahnge with enums. Even Java allows it, is there a way to fix it or should I try something else in the code below? Pretty sure it's a bug because my code seems correct. Btw, I'm trying to implement lock-free stack with backoff elimination.

```
        public enum State
        {
            Empty,
            LoadingItem,
            Waiting,
            Busy
        }
    
        public class Exchanger
        {
            public State Staaate;
            public int Item;
        }
    
        List<Exchanger> eliminationArray = new List<Exchanger>();
    
        bool tryPushEliminationArray()
        {
    
            foreach (Exchanger exchanger in eliminationArray)
            {
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange<State>(ref exchanger.Staaate, State.Busy, State.Busy) != State.Busy)
                {
    
                }
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry, there is no support for enums ... [use int](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ls4EC3)

Comment: ... [or enum like object](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UrPBPz) (with all the consequences)

Comment: @Selvin `Unsafe.As` with `ref` returns would work

Comment: `if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Unsafe.As<State, int>(ref exchanger.State), (int)State.Busy, (int)State.Busy) != (int)State.Busy)` https://dotnetfiddle.net/HzsbOz Note that no actual conversion happens.

Answer (score -2):

As a C# dev with 5+ years of experience, I can say that it's a shame you can't simply use CompareExchange to change int or enum. Try creating a new exchanger with new state, I know it's gonna take extra memory but there's no other way around it...

Comment: *...you can't simply use CompareExchange to change int...* ... **this is not true** :D YOU CAN use `CompareExchange` with `int`

Comment: well, I tried it int to and it gave me the same error

Comment: do not use generic ... there are 10 overloaded `CompareExchange` versions ...

Comment: Oh wait, it does work with ints and floats, but I still can't make it work with enums